# Populate Radio buttons and submit value to query database

Tags: php, sql, html, forms

I am trying to learn programming and have to populate a set of radio buttons and submit what is selected to show records from a database. I have already done this with a selection list, but can't quite understand what I need to change to convert it to a radio buttons.

**Selection list:**

```
<?php 
require_once("dbconn.php");
$sql = "SELECT staffName, staffID FROM staff";  
$rs = mysqli_query($dbConn, $sql) or die ('Problem with query' . mysqli_error($dbConn));
?>

<form id="task9" action="task7.php" method="get">   
    <select name="staffID" id="staffID">
    <?php
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs)) { 
        $name=$row["staffName"];
        $staffIden=$row["staffID"];
        echo "<option value=".$staffIden.">".$name."</option>";
    }
    ?>  
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" method="get">
    <input type="reset"  name="reset">
</form>
```

**Radio buttons (all I get is all the names and only One radio button):**

```
<?php 
require_once("dbconn.php");
$sql = "SELECT staffName, staffID FROM staff";  
$rs = mysqli_query($dbConn, $sql) or die ('Problem with query' . mysqli_error($dbConn));
?>

<form id="task9" action="task7.php" method="get">   
    <input type = "radio" name="staffID" id="staffID">
    <?php
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs)) { 
        $name=$row["staffName"];
        $staffIden=$row["staffID"];
        echo "<option value=".$staffIden.">".$name."</option>";
    }
    ?>
```

Hopefully this question is clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using below code.

```
<?php 
   require_once("dbconn.php");
   $sql = "SELECT staffName, staffID FROM staff";  
   $rs = mysqli_query($dbConn, $sql)
      or die ('Problem with query' . mysqli_error($dbConn));
?>

<form id="task9" action="task7.php" method="get">   

<?php
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs)) { 
 $name=$row["staffName"];
 $staffIden=$row["staffID"];
 echo "<label>";
 echo "<input type='radio' name='staffID' value='".$staffIden."'/> ";
 echo $name;
 echo "</label><br/>";
 }
 ?> 

 <br><br>

<input type="submit" name="submit" method="get">
<input type="reset"  name="reset">
</form>
```

Comment: legend. Works a treat.!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php 
  require_once("dbconn.php");
 $sql = "SELECT staffName, staffID FROM staff";  
  $rs = mysqli_query($dbConn, $sql)
  or die ('Problem with query' . mysqli_error($dbConn));
 ?>

 <form id="task9" action="task7.php" method="get">   

<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs)) { 
 $name=$row["staffName"];
$staffId=$row["staffID"];
?>

 <input type='radio' name='staffID' value='<?php echo $staffId  ?>'/>
 <?php echo $name; ?>
 <br/>
 <?php
 }
 ?> 

 <br/><br/>

 <input type="submit" name="submit" method="get">
 <input type="reset"  name="reset">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

to add to what is there you will likely need to add either some code to your task7.php file to handle the database actions or if the file is task7.php you will need to add a block to the top of your file to handle the self-submitted form